# Activating an iOS app when Bluetooth connection connects

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, bluetooth

Is such a thing possible? I know certain apps such as VOIP apps have permission to run constantly, but I'm uncertain my app idea would be allowed to always run.

Comment: You need to flesh the question out with more details about what you're trying to do. Presumably BTLE? What does the app need to do as a result? Will it be broadcasting as a beacon, or you're talking about hardware device connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "Activating an app".

You can operate as a Bluetooth Central in background mode and your app can receive notifications that a Bluetooth Low Energy service has been detected (if you are scanning for that service) or a device has connected (if you have a pending connect for that device).

You can then interact with the peripheral briefly (transfer a small amount of information for example) or display a notification to the user, but you cannot bring your app to the foreground preempting whatever the user is currently doing.

This project demonstrates CoreBluetooth background connection - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground